# How to set the actionbar home icon to show three bars like YouTube, etc.?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, slidingmenu

I'm trying to figure out how to implement the 'three bar' animated indicator on the home icon as used in many of Google's apps. I'm using ActionBarSherlock, and just wondering what is the easiest way to set the up indicator programmatically when I toggle my slidingmenu, so that it shrinks and expands those three bars?

Comment: What is your sliding menu implementation? If it is `DrawerLayout`, use `ActionBarDrawerToggle`.

Comment: it's https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu - should I change?

Comment: "should I change?" -- I can't answer that. However, the recipe for adding the icon to the action bar varies by sliding menu implementation.